# I want to redirect a controller with AJAX in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to handle a 'NEXT' button on a webpage.

My Need: When the user clicks on the 'Next' button, the requested url posts with using a JQuery AJAX call to a function in the controller: `testurlredirect()`. This function determines the next URL.

This is what I've tried:

**My controller** function is:

```
public function testurlredirect(){
  redirect("mycontrollername");
}
```

**My jquery** code in view is:

```
$("#next").click(function(){
  $.post("<?php echo 'http://www.domain.com/testapp/testurlredirect';?>",
  {
    name:"testname",
    city:"mycity"
  },
  function(data,status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });
});
```

I also check this URL by echoing "hello" in b/w the function, but this message appears when I directly pasted it in a browser. When I handle the click this message does not appear in console. It just show sthe link in red color (acts like an error).

Can you please tell me what I'm missing, or doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you doing this `$.post("<?php echo 'http://www.domain.com/testapp/testurlredirect';?>"` instead of just writing the URL? `$.post("http://www.domain.com/testapp/testurlredirect"`

Comment: Why don't you just get and return the next page in testurlredirect() ?

Comment: dear popnoodles,  Still facing the same issue after removing the php

Comment: Check and make sure you aren't facing any errors. $.post will fail if you use the default redirect() function in Codeigniter. jQuery will consider a 302 redirect (the default) an error. If you look in the jQuery source code you'll find this success determination code:
 isSuccess = status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 304;

Answer (score 2):

This may be a silly question.. but why run an ajax call just to reload the page anyways? Would a regular a href not do exactly the same thing but with less hassle? 
If it were me I would have the function called do something like..

```
public function LoadNextPage($page)
{
    $this->load->view($page);
}
```

Then after the post you can use the returned data to change the pages content

```
function(data,status){
    $('#pageWrapper').html(data);
}
```

I may be missing something, but hopefully that helps.